# A/B Test Significance Analysis

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, p-value

We're performing an A/B test on mobile users to see a configuration change has a significant effect or not. The change is supposed to increase the values of the advertisements (ads) shown to users. In our experiment, we had ~5K users on each variant (say Variant A, Variant B). Every user has been shown different number of ads depending on their session lengths. For example, some users can see up to 1K ads, and some users see only 2-3 ads. In total we show ~150K ads to users in each variant.

While we're quantifying the significance of the improvement, we sum the ad revenues for each user and therefore obtain a ~5K array of user values for each variant, i.e. $n_1\approx n_2\approx 5K$. The data is like:

`Variant A : [1$, 1.3$, ..., 0.5$], Variant B : [1.1$, 0.3$, ..., 0.9$]`

where each array entry denotes the ad revenue generated from that specific user. Then, we apply a statistical test to see what p-value we have. It's one question of which test to use but that is not our main concern right now. The p-value we calculated turned out to be $p\approx 0.42$.

However, **another way** of doing this could have been comparing the values of the ads directly, instead of summing them for users and comparing user values, i.e. $n_1\approx n_2\approx 150K$, and data will be like:

`Variant A : [0.01$, 0.00013$, ..., 0.005$], Variant B : [0.001$, 0.03$, ..., 0.00009$]`

Now, we have two arrays of size nearly 150K, and once we do a statistical test, we got $p\approx 0.006$.

Actually, in both cases, the percent improvement is around $1\%$. But, since it's with different sample sizes, tests result in different significance (p) values. In the industry, we generally tend to evaluate A/B tests on a user basis, but in this specific problem, we couldn't be sure which formulation is the right one. Any advices?

Comment: The way forward really depends on what question you want to answer.  If you are looking to assess the per user revenue, then the first approach seems best.  I would have to know more about the design and what was the point of the experiment to say more.

Comment: I never see the concept of A/B testing mentioned without thinking of this blog post: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=132.

Comment: @DemetriPananos the configuration we tried actually aims to increase the "ad-value" of a single advertisement, in the hope of making more money. In mobile industry, we generally report back to non-technical people saying that avg revenue per user in Variant A: X\$, Variant B: Y\$, and the difference is significant or not. But, in this case, while avg. ad value is increasing significantly, average user value increased but not significantly. I'm wondering what a statistician would do in my position.

Comment: @cross-entropy In your entropy, I would report the statistic of interest, namely the revenue per user.  Significance is also not a good thing to report by itself; a difference between groups + a confidence interval for that difference is more meaningful.

Comment: @DemetriPananos thank you very much for your input! Do you think it makes sense to say this: "Average ad value increases significantly but average user value doesn't"?

Comment: I would avoid the term significance all together, and isntead focus on the size of the difference for the relevant question.  Significance on its own is meaningless without context.